# Sum in Column based on condition in rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on one data frame, where I wanted sum of values where row values are similar,
In the below code, I want to sum Quantity if Fruit names are similar. For that, I tried group by but it gives output as just one value whereas I want to reflect similarly in the data frame to carry out further operations.
Code i have tried:

```
data = {'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Grape', 'Melon'],
        'Quantity':[3,4,3,20,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.groupby('Fruit')['Quantity'].sum()
```

Output I am getting is:

```
Fruit
Apple      3
Banana     7
Grape     20
Melon      1
Name: Quantity, dtype: int64
```

The Result I want is:

```
    Fruit   Quantity
0   Apple   3
1   Banana  7
2   Grape   20
3   Melon   1
```

Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Use `df.groupby('Fruit')['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()` or `df.groupby('Fruit', as_index=False)['Quantity'].sum()`

Comment: @jezrael. thanks a lot, I am very grateful to you. you solved my problem within secs. :)